# microtype package (v.2.5 beta 06) and footnote protrusion

Tags: footnotes, microtype, protrusion

According to section 6 of `microtype` manual (v.2.5 from 2011/02/07, p. 23) the code below should set custom protrusion for footnote numbers. However, when `\microtypecontext` command is set, it cancels footnote mark completely. I run lualatex (beta-0.70.1-2011061410), but it isn't important if you're using pdflatex or xelatex, the result is same. Ideas?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper,showframe}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,factor=2000]{microtype}

\makeatletter

\SetProtrusion[context=footnote]%
    {font=*/*/*/*/scriptsize}% adapt if necessary; "footnotesize" corrected to "scriptsize" after Werner's note
    {1={,650},%
    2={,400},%
    3={,400},%
    4={,400},%
    5={,400},%
    6={,400},%
    7={,500},%
    8={,400},%
    9={,400},%
    0={,400}}

\newcommand*\new@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont
    \microtypecontext{protrusion=footnote}\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand*\@footnotemark{%
    \leavevmode \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
    \new@makefnmark \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi \relax}

\makeatother

%\setcounter{footnote}{123}

\begin{document}

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
%
\footnote{A footnote}
%
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

\end{document}
```

Note that the version of microtype package is [2.5 beta 06](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423) which supports xelatex and tracking feature for lualatex.

The same question asked at [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/p9H3QuOkAHk/discussion). I'll sync them if necessary.

---

**UPDATE**: Robert made couple of replies at comp.text.tex and solved most of problems regarding this issue by updating the package (microtype beta is now 2.5 beta 08). The only one that still remains is that numbers throughout a document (not only footnotes) are always lining nums, meaning `Lowercase` and `Proportional` options to `fontspec` get ignored, so text figures cannot be used in normal fashion. With `Renderer=Basic` option to `fontspec`, `Numbers=Lowercase` option gets applied, but `Numbers=Proportional` still does not.

Comment: Did you notice the warning in the log file?

Comment: Yes. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 8):

As @Thorsten mentioned, the problem is that `microtype` is unable to associate your protrusion settings properly with the footnote. This is because you only specify the font type via the incorrect size - `\footnotesize` in this case. The warning produced by pdfTeX is

```
Package microtype Warning: I cannot find a protrusion list for font
(microtype)                `OT1/cmr/m/n/7' (context: `footnote'). Switching off
(microtype)                protrusion for this font on input line 40.
```

resulting in:

[image: Incorrect microtype protrusion]

Using either

```
{font=*/*/*/*/scriptsize}% adapt if necessary
```

or

```
{encoding=OT1}% You could add `,family=cmr` to be more specific
```

instead of

```
{font=*/*/*/*/footnotesize}% adapt if necessary
```

which, instead, yields:

[image: Correct microtype protrusion]

I am using TeXLive 2011 under Windows with `microtype` v2.4. The example in *my* documentation that you highlighted used the same modification to the above suggestion. I obtain a similar result under lualatex, but I know that `microtype` is not supported under `xelatex`, producing the following warning:

```
Package microtype Warning: You don't seem to be using pdftex.
(microtype)                `microtype' only works with pdftex.
(microtype)                Try running `pdflatex' instead of `xelatex'.
```

Comment: So that's where the problem lies: version 2.4 indeed works with both pdflatex and lualatex, but v.2.5 (which I'm using because of xelatex and tracking support for lualatex) does not. Thanks for the info about v.2.4.