# Strange behaviour of \textsection in footnote with fixltx2e

Tags: fonts, footnotes, microtype, latin-modern

This is a follow-up question to [How do I enable protrusion for footnotes with \fnsymbol using microtype?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109265/21591), and my answer there.

The MWE that I provided there

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  %% <- this gives problems

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper,showframe}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\usepackage[protrusion=alltext,factor=2000]{microtype}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet{alltextAndFootnotes}{%
  encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2}, %% alltext
  font     = {OMS/lmsy/m/n/scriptsize},
}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=alltextAndFootnotes}
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote]{encoding=OMS, family=lmsy,series=m, shape=n, size=scriptsize}{%
  "03={,650},%% *
  "78={,650},%% \mathsection
  "79={,650},%% \dagger
  "7A={,650},%% \ddagger
  "7B={,650},%% \mathparagraph
  "6B={,650},%% \|
  }
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote,load=lmr-T1,factor = 700]
  {encoding=T1, family=lmr, series=m, shape=n, size=scriptsize}
  {  }
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote,load=cmr-OT1,factor = 700]
  {encoding=OT1, family=lmr, series=m, shape=n}
  {  }

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\new@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont
    \microtypecontext{protrusion=footnote}\@thefnmark}}}
\patchcmd{\@footnotemark}
  {\@makefnmark}
  {\new@makefnmark}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%% --------------------------------------------------------------
%% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{A footnote}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{B}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{C}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{D}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{E}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{F}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{G}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{H}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.

Here's some text to show the behaviour of footnote marker at%
\footnote{I}
the end of a line, which disappears when the code for setting  microtypecontext is used in fnmark redefinition.
\end{document}
```

works fine for me, **until I add the `fixltx2e` package**.

I am aware of the fact that this package changes the default defintion of `\@fnsymbol` from

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath {\ifcase #1\or *\or \dagger \or \ddagger \or \mathsection \or \mathparagraph \or \|\or **\or \dagger \dagger \or \ddagger \ddagger \else \@ctrerr \fi }}
```

to

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ifcase #1\or \TextOrMath \textasteriskcentered *\or \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger \or \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or \TextOrMath \textsection \mathsection \or \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph \or \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered }{**}\or \TextOrMath {\textdagger \textdagger }{\dagger \dagger }\or \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl \textdaggerdbl }{\ddagger \ddagger }\else \@ctrerr \fi }
```

This means that now `\textsection` is used as a footnote symbol, and it is the only one that does not protrude:

[image: sample output]

I don't see what is so special about `\textsection`, when, e.g., `\textparagraph` works fine. What is the reason for that bevaviour, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\textsection` is special because unlike the others it also exists in `T1` encoding (declared in `t1enc.def`, which is loaded by `fontenc`). Now, when latex is asked to typeset a text symbol, it will first check whether this symbol is declared in the current encoding, which in this case will be `T1`. There are two possibilities to solve this:

- either add `\textsection` to the `T1` set:

```
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote]
   {encoding=T1, family=lmr, series=m, shape=n, size=scriptsize}
   { \textsection={,650} }
```

- or, which seems the cleaner approach, undeclare the `\textsection` command in `T1`, so that the symbol from `OMS` (declared in `omsenc.def`, loaded by the format) is used instead:

```
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textsection}{T1}
```

Another remark: Even though `fixltx2e` changes the footnote definition to use text symbols instead of math symbols, the glyphs actually still come from the math font (`OMS`). To really use symbols from a text font, you might want to additionally load the `textcomp` package, and declare the protrusion settings for `TS1/lmr` instead of `OMS/lmsy`. (The issue with `\textsection` will have to be addressed in the same way as above.)

While this won't make any difference with Latin or Computer Modern, where the symbols are the same in math and text fonts, it will for other fonts that are not accompanied by math fonts (say, Times New Roman). Without `textcomp`, the footnote symbols would hence be selected from Computer Modern, which is not what you would want.

So, to wrap this up, I would suggest to do the following:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textsection}{T1}
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote]{font=TS1/*/m/n/scriptsize}{%
  \textasteriskcentered={,650},
  \textsection={,650},
  \textdagger={,650},
  \textdaggerdbl={,650},
  \textparagraph={,650},
  \textbardbl={,650},
  }
\SetProtrusion[context=footnote] % dummy declaration
  {font=T1/*/m/n/scriptsize}
  {  }
```

Comment: Oh god, I looked on the T1 table in fontenc.pdf, *and did not see it*, possibly because it is "hidden" among accented characters. Thanks!